# WPF - Setting tab order on large number of controls

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a large amount of controls (textboxes) as you can see below, but there are around 30 rows of this. These are loaded using arrays, and each column represents an array. So when I hit tab in a textbox, instead of tabbing horizontally, it tabs vertically instead.

Is there a way to set the tab order so it will tab horizontally, aside from changing the way the controls are loaded?

Another quirk is that when leaving one textbox, instead of focusing the next, it just kind of highlights the textbox, and I have to tab a second time to get inside the next textbox.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Main view (lots of code has been omitted, I'm pretty sure nothing has been left out that needs to be here)

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">   
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

ItemsView

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Item}">
      <views:ItemView/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding item <!-- about 30 different items here, omitted for readability -->}" />
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

ItemView

```
<UserControl ... IsTabStop="False">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
</UserControl>
```

The ItemView is nested in the ItemsView, which is nested in the MainView. Since the textboxes are generated based on the array values, I can't easily set the TabIndex property unless there is a way I don't know about (I am pretty new at WPF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`TabIndex` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.tabindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides a way to control the tab order independently of the order controls are loaded.

Usage example:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox TabIndex="2" /><!-- will receive focus second -->
    <TextBox TabIndex="1" /><!-- will receive focus first-->
</Grid>
```

I would guess the unwanted focusing you are seeing is due to a parent UserControl that your TextBoxes are placed in.

If this is the case, you could prevent that by setting `IsTabStop="false"` on that parent control.

For example:

```
<UserControl .... IsTabStop="False">
    <Grid>
        <!-- other graphics -->
        <TextBox TabIndex="1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

**Using a view model to populate the data**

```
public class CellViewModel
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public int TabIndex { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<CellViewModel>> GetMatrix(
    List<List<double>> matrixValues)
{
    var columnCount = matrixValues.Count;
    return matrixValues
        .Select((x, i) => GetColumn(x, columnCount, i));
}

public IEnumerable<CellViewModel> GetColumn(
    List<double> columnValues,
    int columnCount,
    int columnIndex)
{
    return columnValues
        .Select((x, i) =>
            new CellViewModel { Value = x, TabIndex = columnIndex + columnCount * i });
}
```

Your `ItemsSource` for your `ListBox` (which you've now changed to `ItemsControl`) should be a new `Matrix` property, which you populate using `GetMatrix()`.

In your ItemView, you would want something like this:

```
<UserControl ... IsTabStop="False">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" TabIndex="{Binding TabIndex}" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I'll add the code to help demonstrate the issue I'm having. I know the TabIndex is how to set it, I just don't know how to do it with the setup I'm working with.

Comment: Also, adding the IsTabStop didn't fix it. Hopefully adding the code will help.

Comment: For the unwanted highlighting, I think the problem may be that you are using a `ListBox` instead of an `ItemsControl`. The main difference between the two is that `ListBox` has a selection feature (which could be controlled with the tab key) while `ItemsControl` doesn't allow for selection.

Comment: For your tab order problem, you might want to consider populating your items using arrays of view models rather than arrays of your raw data. The view model could have a `TabIndex` property, which you could then bind to. I'll try to flesh this out in my answer.

Comment: Quick question: your `ListBox` (which I think should be an `ItemsControl`) uses a `WrapPanel`, but isn't the desired layout just a horizontal `StackPanel`?

Comment: Yes. I changed the ListBox to an ItemsControl, but no dice. And honestly, I'm pretty new to WPF so I'm not sure the best way to go about some things.

Comment: Chat is blocked here at work...ugh. One more thing, GetColumn has the parameter columnIndex, but I don't see where that comes from.

Comment: OK, that's fixed now.

Comment: I had to modify it a bit to fit my view model, but it works. Thanks!